# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Wifi not working after kernel updates

Tags: kernel, 18.04, iwlwifi

Dell laptop is installed with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS version, after kernel updated to **4.15.0-24-generic** from 4.15.0-23-generic made wifi non functional. Wifi is not showing under settings menu.

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
```

Comment: Reboot using the -23 kernel. If WiFi works on -23 but not -24, then please file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same problem with wifi not working after going to 4.15.0-24.   Running 16.04.3 on MACBook.  I had to back out to kernel 4.13.0-45

Looks like the 4.15.0-24 has larger issues as well.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/linux/+bug/1779827

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Make sure you execute this soon after upgrading the kernel and before rebooting your PC if you are using Wifi, otherwise you will need a wired internet connection to do reinstallation

Comment: dell latitude E6540 seems to just not see the wifi. also the wifi light does not come on. The wifi button is ON (I think) i.e. not RED.